# Cookie Always return Null

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

I have a cookie created in the server side as below

```
   HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["mycookie"];

    if (cookie == null)
    {
        cookie = new HttpCookie("mycookie");
        cookie.HttpOnly = false;
        cookie.Path = "/";
        cookie.Values["mycookie"] = ExpressDate;
    }
```

But everytime there is a postback the cookie loses its value. Can anybody help?

FYI : I have tried it without specify a cookie path as well. But it didnt work either.

Comment: You don't show that you ever add it to the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the new cookie to the response:

```
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```